# How to consume messages from a queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, rate-limiting, sqslistener

I have a scenario wherein I am supposed to consume messages from an AWS SQS.

I know `@SqsListener` can be used or something like that?

Thanks

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-delay-queues.html

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40752610

Comment: Thanks @niko. I'll try this and update here if it serves the purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there a feature that AWS provides to rate-limit the consumption from SQS

The short & long answer is no.

AWS SDKs do not provide a native way to rate-limit consumption from SQS. It is up to you to implement custom logic to rate-limit message consumption.